# Address already in use error if 2+ arquillian integration tests

Tags: tomcat7, jboss-arquillian

I have several 'standard' junit integration test with arquillian, tomcat7 embedded (arquillian-tomcat-embedded-7:1.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT, tomcat-embed-core:7.0.50) and Shrinkwrap.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestMe {

@Deployment
public static WebArchive deploy() {
    return
        ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .addPackages(true, "org.foo")           
            .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/context.xml", "context.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("WEB-INF/beans.xml", "beans.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("WEB-INF/web.xml", "web.xml").as(WebArchive.class);
}
@Test ...
}
```

Separately executed via maven, every test is green. But if I do a *mvn verify* and start the whole testsuite I get: **java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind :9095**. What is the problem?

arquillian.xml:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

<defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />
<engine>
    <property name="deploymentExportPath">target</property>
</engine>
<container qualifier="tomcat" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="unpackArchive">true</property>
        <property name="bindAddress">localhost</property>
        <property name="bindHttpPort">9095</property>
        <property name="serverName">amgui-arquillian-tomcat7-embedded</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like mvn verify is trying to run tests in parallel. Or at least not waiting for the previous test to clean up before it starts the next one. You can't have more than one process binding to the same address/port combination.

Tomcat connectors support the concept of using a new free port every time they start to avoid these sorts of issues (set the port to zero) but I don't think that on its own will help you. Your test environment would need to know to query Tomcat to find out which port to use for every test.

I'd try and modify your tests so they don't run in parallel.

Comment: I didn't add any options for parallel test execution to surefire. I rather think, that Tomcat1 isn't completely stopped when tomcat2 already starts. For jboss-arquillian-embedded there is a configuration option to add a range of ports to use, if the current port is in use... :(

Comment: Thanks! Saved me hours